# How to compile & install Emerald window manager in Ubuntu 13.04 64bit?

Tags: 13.04, compiling, gcc, emerald

Please give me directions to compile & install Emerald specifically in **Raring Ringtail 64bit** edition. I've tried to compile it from the source many times, but had no luck.(Compile log : http://paste.ubuntu.com/5612178/)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### how to compile under 13.04

The keypart of your compile error was the following:

```
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: undefined reference to symbol 'exp@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'exp@@GLIBC_2.2.5' is defined in DSO /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 so try adding it to the linker command line
```

This shows that you need to link to the correct library - you do this by slightly altering the `./configure` command.

The instructions you have linked to also need an additional change to the `./configure` command to ensure that the path to the default libraries are known.

To summarise the compilation:

```
sudo apt-get install git autoconf libtool libwnck1.0-cil-dev libwnck-dev intltool libdecoration0-dev gawk compizconfig-settings-manager

wget cgit.compiz.org/fusion/decorators/emerald/snapshot/emerald-0.9.5.tar.gz

tar -zxvf emerald-0.9.5.tar.gz && cd emerald-0.9.5/

./autogen.sh
make clean
make distclean
./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib${LIBDIRSUFFIX} LIBS='-ldl -lm'
make
sudo make install
```

### some pretty pictures

After running `emerald --replace &` in a terminal you should see the translucent emerald *beryl red* window decoration theme

[image: pic]

Comment: Great answer, but the source code link in your `wget` command is now broken. I used the source from here: https://codeload.github.com/compiz-reloaded/emerald/zip/master. I was able to build Emerald successfully on Mint/mate 18 with this source.